# Too much recursion/Maximum call stack size exceeded (Jquery 1.9.1)

Tags: jquery, recursion, callstack

I am getting 'Too much recursion' error on Firefox and 'Maximum call stack size exceeded at Function.acceptData' on Chrome only on **mobile devices**. This error was not there earlier but after I loaded Jquery 3.4.1 on head for analytics, its throwing this error. The page dependencies already has Jquery 1.9.1. Has anyone faced the same issue or can anyone help me with what is causing this error?

Again, this error only occurs for mobile devices.

Comment: Please provide the code you have written.

Comment: @mzedeler Actually its a huge code and lots of plugins are used, so I'm not sure what is causing this error.

Comment: Then start removing code until the bug goes away. That will lead you to find where the error is.

Comment: @mzedeler Thanks. Can you help with which jquery function or code can possibly cause this.

Comment: No, because as you said, there is a lot of code. You should try the approach I described above.

Comment: Thanks @mzedeler. I updated the jQuery version to 2.1.0 and the issue got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the Jquery from 1.9.1 to 2.1.0.
It worked and no longer throws the 'too much recursion' error.